# Where to put these kind of queries in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

I have an entity `Institute` and a repository `InstituteRepository` which fetches `Institute` objects based on criteria passed. Now somewhere in my application, I need `ViewCount` for the institute (No. of times the institute page has been viewed, which is stored and updated in a database table).

I cache my `Institute` objects, but since ViewCount is very dynamic, I would like to fetch it afresh everytime. Question is, where should I put my `getViewCount()` function?

Can I have a function like `getViewCount()` in `InstituteRepository`? If not, what's the best place for it?

Appreciate any help and sorry for the vague title.

Answer (score 4):

This would definitely fit in a separate bounded context that tracks "viewing related behavior". No need for a repository. Assuming you're using a relational datastore, just do an "insert into InstituteViewRecord (instituteid, user-who-viewed-id, date-and-time-of-viewing) values (...)" to track this information and a "select count(*) from InstituteViewRecord where instituteid = ". KISS. Any remoting needs can be satisfied using RPC or other mechanisms of messaging. I doubt this functionality is core domain.

Comment: +1, application of DDD patterns is probably not required here. You can even strip this down to one table containing a simple counter for every view.

Comment: But where do I write these queries? Should I write them in DAO and use DAO directly wherever I need?

Comment: Yes, what's wrong with that? Think about it this way: what is the extra abstraction buying me & do I really need to apply the same pattern everywhere?